# Will PickupDeliveryLocation work when using an outgoing mail server on a different domain than our own?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

What happens when the outgoing mail server is not part of the local domain?  For example, I work for company xyz.com and our smtp server is mail.xyz.com.  We host client sites in a multitennant application.  We allow our users to point to their own smtp server using email configurations we store in our database.

The code we use to send emails loads the configuration with the smtp information and the authorization needed to send an email on behalf of our clients through their email system.

Currently we are running into concurrency issue that is causing timeouts for various clients when notifications are being processed.  They are currently configured to be sent immediately.  I've read that moving to the local pickup directory can solve this issue.

I am concerned if I specify a path like C:\Temp\Mail but use an SMTP connection to a clients mail server is that going to work?  Doesn't the email being created and sent from the pickup location need to be on the same domain as the smtp server?

How will the clients SMTP server know .eml file has been generated for their domain and needs to be sent out without having to change our client's environment?   If someone can provide any information as to how the SMTP and Specified Pickup Locations work I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The basic operation of an SMTP server in this sense is to monitor a specific set of folders and perform an action when an event occurs. Where your concern is is in that a file dropped into the pickup location is parsed and sent.

The basic SMTP operation allows any email server to send any email regardless of the domain that the email says it is from. This obviously caused issues with fraudulent emails and has been mitigated originally by *Designated Sender* and further extended via SPF, DIM, and DMARC.

So what your client would need to do is to have their SMTP setup properly and configured for your email domain(s). On your end it would be recommended to only allow the *Designated Senders* generate emails, and set up SPF etc for those clients as well

Microsoft has a good article on the SMTP basics [How SMTP Works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480390.aspx)
Google has plenty of lists for SPF, DKIM, and DMARC as well.